# SSL Hitch massive performance decrease

Tags: ssl, varnish

I'm testing around with loader.io and noticed SSL (termination) in front of varnish serves very badly.

My Digital Ocean [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHAsi.png) seems to show Disk I/O maxed at 1.21MB/s (isn't this incredibly low? My M4 SSD runs around 1.500MB/s which is not the same as 1.5 right?)

The [loader.io stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbWYW.png) with 3000 requests per second

```
Cache-Control:  max-age=333s
```

**I have setup Hitch as SSL termination like so:**

```
sudo nano /etc/hitch/hitch.conf
# ADD:
## Basic hitch config for use with Varnish and Acmetool

# Listening
frontend = "[*]:443"
ciphers = "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"

# Send traffic to the Varnish backend using the PROXY protocol
backend = "[::1]:6086"
write-proxy-v2 = on

# List of PEM files, each with key, certificates and dhparams
pem-file = "/var/lib/acme/live/website.io/haproxy"
# END ADD
```

**And varnish like so:**

```
sudo nano /etc/varnish/acmetool.vcl
# ADD: 
backend acmetool {
   .host = "127.0.0.1";
   .port = "402";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/") {
        set req.backend_hint = acmetool;
        return(pass);
    }
}
# END ADD


# include acmetool settings in default.vcl
cp /dev/null /etc/varnish/default.vcl
sudo nano /etc/varnish/default.vcl
# ADD:
vcl 4.0;
import std;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (std.port(local.ip) == 80) {
        set req.http.x-redir = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
        return(synth(850, "Moved permanently"));
    }
}
sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 850) {
        set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
        set resp.status = 301;
        return (deliver);
    }
}

include "/etc/varnish/acmetool.vcl";
# END ADD
```

**What's wrong with my setup and how can I improve performance?**

Answer (score 0):

First, you must check that Varnish is effectively caching the output. Use `varnishstat` (count hits vs misses), or even better use `varnishhist`. You should see responses between 1e-5 and 1e-4 (so between 0.01 ms and 0.1 ms). Note that hits are represented with `|` and misses with `#`.

Another possible issue is Hitch, as I hit this today: `syslog` was filed with «Too many open files». So look at your syslog, to see if you have the same issue. To fix it under `systemd`, you need to add a `LimitNOFILE` in the `[Service]` section of your `hitch.service` file.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this issue when we've been running SSLTermination on the same server as varnish. We ended up having to increase the ulimit on max files open, and making varnish store cached items in RAM instead of on the disk.

Nginx has a habit of breaking the ulimits when you're running a lot of traffic through https. You might need to tweak that to get it optimized properly.